# How to Set click listener on marker in google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

i have two marker in example where one is for current location and one is 
for destination i have drawn a Route path between them but now in same example
i want to set a click listener on both the marker can you suggest some good 
example related this ..?

Comment: marker on a map? wich map? some more infos or a screenshot would be cool

Comment: in google map example.

Comment: by default the onclick on the polyline is disabled. You can enable it via [setOnPolylineClickListener(GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setOnPolylineClickListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener))

Comment: I bet this is answered in the official guide. If you followed that guide, show your code to find the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you would go about adding an `onClick` listener for markers on a map:

```
GoogleMap mMap;
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(
   new MarkerOptions()
       .position(new LatLng(dLat, dLong))
       .title("Your title")                                       
       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin)));

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker m) {}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is how to do it using Kotlin:

```
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap  //declaration inside class

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener { marker ->
        if (marker.isInfoWindowShown) {
            marker.hideInfoWindow()
            } else {
            marker.showInfoWindow()
            }
        true
        }
}
```

Hope this helps some beginner like me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let your class/fragment implement `OnMarkerClickListener`
2. Register marker click callback to your googleMap with `googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);` in your setup
3. Override the `onMarkerClick`

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
       //handle click here      
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of Google Maps, this is no longer valid, you should use:

```
MarkerManager(mMap).newCollection().apply {
    addMarker(MarkerOptions()
        .position(it)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)))

        setOnMarkerClickListener {
            //handleClick    
        }
}
```